# How can I protect myself from oil splatter on my hand/wrist/arm?

Tags: food, personal-care

How can I protect myself from oil splatter on my hand/wrist/arm? A little splash now and then is fine, but when frying something particularly oily like fish some of these splashes hurt! It also seems to have the effect of drying skin after being exposed to these splashes daily.

Comment: Are gloves out of the question?

Comment: @AdamZuckerman Nope, it's definitely a valid suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I have used welder's sleeves when working a deep fryer. No more pockmarks on my forearms! They will probably cost you less than $10 from your local hardware store.

Here's an example:
http://www.homedepot.com/p/Lincoln-Electric-Fire-Resistant-Black-Welding-Sleeves-KH813/205141550

These are 21" long, and they're designed to block hot sparks and metal bits. They work well for tiny bits of oil splatter. (Of course, they would not protect from a hot oil SPILL.)

Alternative: Here's an 18" glove that's specifically designed for hot oil fryers:
http://www.centralrestaurant.com/Fryer-Glove-with-Removable-Liner-c103p24074.html

Answer (score 1):

Splatter guards or splash screens are helpful. Though [available online](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00061N0J6), they may be sold locally for US$1 or so. You could make your own from a layer or two of fine metal window screen, held together with a central bolt for a handle.

[image]

This works well for me, and only a few stray splatters exit when flipping fried foods. BTW, don't buy one with a heavy handle, which increases the likelihood of the guard from falling off the pan.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the handle of your frying pan with longer one and use a longer fork to put and take the products you are frying. This way you will increased the distance from the pan and will experience less splashes on your hands. And the splashes which reach your hands will be with lower temperature when reaching your hand.

Use a light material for the new handle and don't make it too long because it may keel over the pan.